# Integral of a trace and divergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, divergence-theorem

I have found the following equality in a paper I am reading and I got stuck because I am not able to check it.

We have a divergence-free, smooth vector field $V \colon \mathbb T^N \to \mathbb T^N$ defined on the torus. It is claimed that
$$
\int_{\mathbb T^N} \text{Tr}[(V \otimes V) \cdot \nabla V] \, dx = 0 
$$
where $dx$ is the standard Lebesgue measure on the torus. My only idea to check this is to resort to some use of integration by parts and the divergence theorem: the "trace" appearing in the integral should be reduced to the divergence of some quantity (using the fact that $\text{div } V = 0$) and then the conclusion would follow by divergence theorem indeed (since we are on the torus).

However, something breaks: in 2D an explicit computation tells me that the integrand is
$$
v_1^2 \partial_1 v_1 + v_2^2 \partial_2v_2 + v_1v_2 (\partial_1 v_2 + \partial_2 v_1)
$$
(with obvious notation for derivatives and $V=(v_1,v_2)$) and I fail to write this as divergence of something, not even using integration by parts or the fact that $\partial_1 v_1 = - \partial_2 v_2$.

I feel there should be some simple (general?) trick behind, but after a night of computations I’m giving up. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following vector fields:
$$X = |V|^2 V = \sum_j V_j^2 V$$
on $\mathbb T^N$. Then by divergence theorem,
$$\int_{\mathbb T^N} \operatorname{div} (X) = 0.$$
Since

\begin{align}
 \operatorname{div} (X) & = \operatorname{div} (|V|^2 V) \\
&= \sum_i \nabla_i (|V|^2 V_i) \\
&= 2 \sum _{i,j} (\nabla_i V_j) V_j V_i + |V|^2 \sum_i \nabla_iV_i \\
&= 2 \sum_{i,j}  V_i V_j  \nabla_i V_j \\
&= 2\operatorname{tr} ( V\otimes V, \nabla V), 
\end{align}

one obtains the result.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot! If I am not wrong, this argument could be slightly generalized: if we have two divergence free fields $V, U$ (on the torus) by using $X = |U|^2 V$ your argument proves $\int_{\mathbb T^N} \text{Tr} (V \otimes U, \nabla U) dx = 0$. Do you agree? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, @Romeo that's true.

Comment: Thanks, good to know! But now I'm getting hungry :) What about $\int_{\mathbb T^N} \text{Tr} (U \otimes V, \nabla U) dx$? Is it also $0$? Or some "asymmetry" is appearing here?

Comment: I believe that would be false. In this situation there does not seem to be a way to use that the divergence of $V$ is zero. @Romeo

Comment: I agree and I thank you again for helping. However, I think it can be proved that $\int_{\mathbb T^n} \text{Tr}(U \otimes V, \nabla U) dx = 0$ provided $\nabla U$ is symmetric - do you agree? (I am using only the definition of inner product - some equalities of the kind $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)=Tr(B^tA)=Tr(AB^t)$ for square matrices $A,B$). Thanks again

Comment: Yes that's true. @Romeo

Comment: So, now the question becomes which are the div-free fields whose jacobian is symmetric... Any hints on this? :) Thanks, you have been very helpful!

Comment: If you formulate that using differential one form, the condition is equivalent to that $U_i dx^i$ is a closed form. So for example when $U = \nabla f$ for some function, then $\nabla U$ is symmetric. @Romeo

Comment: That makes sense, you are right. Thanks once more, hope to meet you again on math.se! ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, integrating by parts and using the fact that $\nabla\cdot v=0$  you have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{T}^N} \mathrm{Tr}((v\otimes v)\cdot\nabla v) = -\int_{\mathbb{T}^N} \mathrm{Tr}(\nabla\cdot(v\otimes v)  \otimes v) = - 0 -\int_{\mathbb{T}^N} \mathrm{Tr}((v\cdot\nabla v) \otimes v) = -\int_{\mathbb{T}^N} \mathrm{Tr}((v\otimes v)\cdot\nabla v)
$$
so
$$
2\int_{\mathbb{T}^N} \mathrm{Tr}((v\otimes v)\cdot\nabla v) = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain how you derived the first equality (that sort of integration by parts for $\otimes$)? I am not able to prove it, nor to find it somewhere in literature. Thank you again for helping!

Comment: This is just the normal integration by parts. If you are not used to vector calculus, you can just do it with coordinates. Then it gives you $$\int \sum_{i,j} v_i v_k \partial_k v_i = -\int \sum_{i,j} \partial_k(v_k v_i) v_i$$ which is exactly my first line ;)

Comment: You are right, that was easy and I was dumb :) (btw I guess in your last comment the index $j$ under the summation symbol should be $k$). Thanks for your help, too!

Comment: Oh yes of course, sum over $i$ and $k$ ...